# Flask with Peewee getting new data only on restart

Tags: python, mysql, flask, peewee

I'm facing a really strange issue with my Flask + Peewee app.

I have an webapp that insert data into MySQL database.

My Flask app connects also to that database with peewee.

The issue is, when i insert something with the webapp If I make a Select to the database within Flask app, it’s returning the data available at the start of the Flask app. To get new data With the same Select I need to restart Flask server service in order to get the new data.

Does anyone knows what's happening?

**UPDATE**

I found the issue. It wasn't directly related with peewee but with Flask.

I have something like this:

```
def some_method(id, user_id, date_from = datetime.now(), limit = 50):
```

It seems that when I do this the **date_from** is setted with the datetime of the compilation. After that, all requests that make use of it use always that date time.

Changed to this:

```
def some_method(id, user_id, date_from = None, limit = 50):

   if (date_from is None):
     date_from = datetime.now()
```

And it start working.

I'm sharing this for other guys like me that could have this same issue.

Answer (score 0):

That's the expected behavior for web applications. HTTP is a stateless protocol, that means your webapp's frontend can't know if your backend's state has been changed unless it makes a new request. Therefor, your backend changes are visible only after you restart the Flask app. Depends on your code, you probably can also see the changes by refresh the browser.

If you want to see the changes immediately without restart/refresh, learn how to use Javascript to query the changes and update the frontend DOM. You can get started by learning jquery, or a modern framework like React/Vue/Angular.

Comment: I’m talking about SQL Select data, not html. Flask app is a rest api without any interface. It only receives GET/POST/PUT requests